# Hide/Show Map Markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone can help please.

I'm trying to put together a script which hides and shows locations on my map. The host code I've been using is [here](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html) and my code is shown below:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
    <title>Google Maps Javascript API v3 Example: Marker Categories</title> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
    <title>Google Maps</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body { height: 100%; } 
</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var customIcons = {
            "Artefact": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            "Coin": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            "Jewellery": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            "Precious Metal": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

      // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
      var side_bar_html = ""; 

      var gmarkers = [];
      var map = null;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 

          // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
function createMarker(point,findname,html,findcategory) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        var icon = customIcons[findcategory],
        shadow: iconShadow,
        map: map,
        title: findname,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
        // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
        marker.mycategory = findcategory;                                 
        marker.myname = findname;
        gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
}

      // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
      function show(findcategory) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == findcategory) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
        // == check the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(findcategory+"box").checked = true;
      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide(findcategory) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == findcategory) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        // == clear the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(findcategory+"box").checked = false;
        // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
        infowindow.close();
      }

      // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,findcategory) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(findcategory);
        } else {
          hide(findcategory);
        }
        // == rebuild the side bar
        makeSidebar();
      }

      function myclick(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
      }


      // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
      function makeSidebar() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
            html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
          }
        }
        document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
      }

  function initialize() {
    var myOptions = {
      zoom:6,  
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });



      // Read the data
  downloadUrl("loadpublicfinds.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
  var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var findname = markers[i].getAttribute("findname");
          var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription");
          var html = "<b>" + 'Find : ' + "</b>" + findname + "<p>" + "<b>" + 'Description: ' + "</b>" + finddescription + "</p>"
          var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,findname,html,findcategory);
        }

        // == show or hide the categories initially ==
        show("Artefact");
        hide("Coin");
        hide("Jewellery");
        hide("Precious Metal");
        // == create the initial sidebar ==
        makeSidebar();
      });
    }

    </script>
  </head>
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 




    <!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout -->
    <table border=1>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <div id="map" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>
        </td>
        <td valign="top" style="width:150px; text-decoration: underline; color: #4444ff;"> 
           <div id="side_bar"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <form action="#">
      Artefact: <input type="checkbox" id="Artefactbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Artefact')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Coin: <input type="checkbox" id="Coinbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Coin')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Jewellery: <input type="checkbox" id="Jewellerybox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Jewellery')" /><br />
      Precious Metal: <input type="checkbox" id="PreciousMetalbox" onclick="boxclick(this,'Precious_Metal')" /><br />
    </form>  

  </body>

</html>
```

When I try and run my code I get the following error: 
Message: Expected identifier, string or number
Line: 42
Char: 1

The line which it points to is this

```
function createMarker(point,findname,html,findcategory) {
```

I'm fairly new to this, but I've run the code through 'Firebug' and it states that the line id 'missing: propertyid' but I must admit I'm not sure what this means.

I just wondered whether someone could take a look at this please and let me know where I'm going wrong.

Many thanks

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Map My Finds - Public Finds</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/publicfinds.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=en"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var customIcons = {
            "Artefact": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            "Coin": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },
            "Jewellery": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            },          "Precious Metal": {
            icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
            shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
            }
            };

               // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
      var side_bar_html = ""; 

      var gmarkers = [];      var markers;

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); 


function createMarker(latlng,name,html,category) { var contentString = html; var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  position: point,  icon: customIcons[findcategory],  shadow: iconShadow,  map: map,  title: findname,  zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5  }); 

     // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
        marker.mycategory = findcategory;                             

        marker.myname = findname;
        gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });

      // == shows all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is checked ==
      function show(findcategory) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == findcategory) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(true);
          }
        }
        // == check the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(findcategory+"box").checked = true;
      }

      // == hides all markers of a particular category, and ensures the checkbox is cleared ==
      function hide(findcategory) {
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].mycategory == findcategory) {
            gmarkers[i].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
        // == clear the checkbox ==
        document.getElementById(findcategory+"box").checked = false;
        // == close the info window, in case its open on a marker that we just hid
        infowindow.close();
      }

      // == a checkbox has been clicked ==
      function boxclick(box,findcategory) {
        if (box.checked) {
          show(findcategory);
        } else {
          hide(findcategory);
        }
        // == rebuild the side bar
        makeSidebar();
      }

      function myclick(i) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i],"click");
      }


      // == rebuilds the sidebar to match the markers currently displayed ==
      function makeSidebar() {
        var html = "";
        for (var i=0; i<gmarkers.length; i++) {
          if (gmarkers[i].getVisible()) {
            html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + i + ')">' + gmarkers[i].myname + '<\/a><br>';
          }
        }
        document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = html;
      }                 function load() { 
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), { 
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(54.312195845815246,-4.45948481875007), 
            zoom:6, 
            mapTypeId: 'terrain' 
            }); 


    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });

            // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file 
            downloadUrl("loadpublicfinds.php", function(data) { 
            var xml = data.responseXML; 
            var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
            for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { 
            var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lat"));
            var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("findosgb36lon"));             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);            var findcategory = markers[i].getAttribute("findcategory");             var findname = markers[i].getAttribute("findname");             var finddescription = markers[i].getAttribute("finddescription");
            var html = "<b>" + 'Find : ' + "</b>" + findname + "<p>" + "<b>" + 'Description: ' + "</b>" + finddescription + "</p>"
            var marker = createMarker(point,findname,html,findcategory);
        }
      // == show or hide the categories initially ==
        show("Artefact");
        hide("Coin");
        hide("Jewellery");      hide("Precious Metal");
        // == create the initial sidebar ==
        makeSidebar();
      });
    }
            function downloadUrl(url, callback) { 
            var request = window.ActiveXObject ? 
            new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : 
            new XMLHttpRequest; 

            request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
            if (request.readyState == 4) { 
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing; 
            callback(request, request.status); 
            } 
            }; 

            request.open('GET', url, true); 
            request.send(null); 
            } 

            function doNothing() {} 
            }
            </script>  </head>     <body onLoad="load()">
                <div id="map"></div> <!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout --> <form action="#">
      Theatres: <input type="checkbox" id="Artefact" onclick="boxclick(this,'Artefact')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Golf Courses: <input type="checkbox" id="Coin" onclick="boxclick(this,'Coin')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
       Golf Courses: <input type="checkbox" id="Jewellery" onclick="boxclick(this,'Jewellery')" /> &nbsp;&nbsp;
      Tourist Information: <input type="checkbox" id="Precious Metal" onclick="boxclick(this,'Precious Metal')" /><br />
       </form>       </body>  </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple syntax errors I noticed:

1.) All of you code was wrapped in the InfoWindow object

change this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  {
```

to this:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

2.) You are setting the icon property wrong in the marker

change this:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        var icon = customIcons[findcategory], //wont work
        shadow: iconShadow,
        map: map,
        title: findname,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
```

to this:

```
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: point,
        icon: customIcons[findcategory],
        shadow: iconShadow,
        map: map,
        title: findname,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });
```

I was not receiving any more syntax errors in Visual Studio after making these changes.

**Edit** to include additional fix:

the downloadUrl function is not defined on this page.  You did not include the script file in the head area of the page.

Add this right after where the Google maps api is referenced:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>`

**Update**

Looks like you changed the name of the `point` parameter to `latlng` in the createMarker function, but did not change it everywhere inside the function.  The position property is still set to `point`.  Also it looks like you might be missing the closing bracket for the create marker function as well.

```
function createMarker(latlng,name,html,category) { 
    var contentString = html; 
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({  
        position: latlng, //changed from 'point' 
        icon: customIcons[findcategory],  
        shadow: iconShadow, 
        map: map, 
        title: findname,  
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5  
    }); 

    // === Store the category and name info as a marker properties ===
    marker.mycategory = findcategory;                             
    marker.myname = findname;
    gmarkers.push(marker);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
    });

} //is this where this function ends?
```

I would recommend that you put all of this script into a separate file and then reference it with a `<script type="text/javascript" src="path to your script" />` tag.  It will make the file easier to maintain and troubleshoot in the future.

Comment: Hi, sincere thanks for looking at & replying to my post. The page looks a lot better now with your changes incorporated into it. However I'm now receiving the following error 'object expected at line 129 character 3', which is this line: 
'downloadUrl("loadpublicfinds.php", function(data) {'
Firebug tells me that the download URL is not defined, but I'm running this script for other pages & other than the fieldnames it's exactly the same. I thought it might the 'var markers...' line preceeding this, so I changed this to a global variable without any luck. Have you an ideas please? Regards.

Comment: I do not see where you have defined the downloadURL() function.  That is why you are getting the error.  Is this function in another script that you may not have referenced on this page?

Comment: Hi, many thanks for replying so quickly. The function isn't defined within the page. As I said earlier I've used this piece of the script for a few of my other pages without any problem. The code originates from here http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3.html
I've been back to my other scripts that are working and the original 'remove markers' demo found here http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_categories.html
The only difference I see is that the original says:
downloadUrl("categories.xml", function(doc) {
var xml = xmlParse(doc);
Could this be it? kind Regards.

Comment: I looked at the source on you working example.  At the top is has `<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>`  This is where the downloadURL function is defined.  This line is not included on the page in this question.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for bearing with me on this. Whilst doing something else today, I recalled seeing the very same line. However, my file is not a JS file it's php, so I don't add this at the top of my script. I've gone through the script and tidied up a bit. I think I've got past the error above, but I'm now getting the error 'object expected at line 164 character 1. I must admit I'm baffled as everything seems ok. I've listed the new code above. Any additional help would be gratefully appreciated. kind regards

Comment: Answer has been updated.  Looks like you still have syntax errors.

Comment: Hi, I really want to say thank you for all your help, and patience on this. I've been back to my code, made some small alterations and I've got it work. Once again many thanks for your hard work and time. Kind regards.